# python3 webscraping- loop returns only one iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

python3 web scraping) I'm trying to extract table from  html data and store it into a new dataframe. I need all the 'td' values but when I try to iterate, the loop only returns the first line, not the all lines. Below is my code and output

```
!pip install yfinance
!pip install pandas
!pip install requests
!pip install bs4
!pip install plotly

import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):
 fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), vertical_spacing = .3)
 stock_data_specific = stock_data[stock_data.Date <= '2021--06-14']
 revenue_data_specific = revenue_data[revenue_data.Date <= '2021-04-30']
 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=stock_data_specific.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=revenue_data_specific.Revenue.astype("float"), name="Revenue"), row=2, col=1)
 fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
 fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
 fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
 fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
 fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
 height=900,
 title=stock,
 xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
 fig.show()

tsla = yf.Ticker("TSLA")
tsla

tesla_data = tsla.history(period="max")
tesla_data


tesla_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
tesla_data.head()

url = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue"
html_data  = requests.get(url).text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])
for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'): 
 col = row.find_all("td")
 date = col[0].text
 revenue = col[1].text
tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue}, ignore_index=True)
tesla_revenue
```

|  | DATE | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2008 | 15$ |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

It works fine but you are appending the data outside of your loop, so you always get the result of your last iteration.

#### How to fix?

Fix your indentation and put the appending part into your loop

```
tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])
for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'): 
    col = row.find_all("td")
    date = col[0].text
    revenue = col[1].text
    tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue}, ignore_index=True)
tesla_revenue
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue"
html_data  = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])
for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all('tr'): 
    col = row.find_all("td")
    date = col[0].text
    revenue = col[1].text
    tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue}, ignore_index=True)
tesla_revenue
```

#### Output

|  | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 | $31,536 |
| 1 | 2019 | $24,578 |
| 2 | 2018 | $21,461 |
| 3 | 2017 | $11,759 |
| 4 | 2016 | $7,000 |
| 5 | 2015 | $4,046 |
| 6 | 2014 | $3,198 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It really helped :) I was struggling with it for hours but now I came to know that the indent was the problem thanks to you :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Find main table using appropriate class and tag

```
res=requests.get("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue")

soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
teable=soup.find("table",class_="historical_data_table table")
main_data=table.find_all("tr")
```

Now append data to list and create list of list data for creaing row data for DataFrame

```
main_lst=[]
for i in main_data[1:]:
    lst=[data.get_text(strip=True) for data in i.find_all("td")]
    main_lst.append(lst)
```

Now use that data to show as `df`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","Price"],data=main_lst)
df
```

Output:

```
    Date    Price
0   2020    $31,536
1   2019    $24,578
2   2018    $21,461
3   2017    $11,759
...
```

In one liner using `pandas`

```
df=pd.read_html("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue")
print(len(df))
print(df[0])
```

Output

```
6

    Date    Price
0   2020    $31,536
1   2019    $24,578
2   2018    $21,461
3   2017    $11,759
```

...

Comment: Wow  another way to solve the problem!! thanks a lot :) I didn't know this kind of way but thanks to you I came to learn by now :)